# 9.04 Only on Dell Inspiron B120

Tags: installation, hardware, inspiron, 9.04

I've been trying to install Ubuntu on my 7 year old Dell Inspiron B120 with very limited success.  I tried installing multiple versions unsuccessfully until I worked my way down to 9.04.  I've gotten it installed and running as well as I can with the limited support I can access.  Why Dell won't even run any new versions that I've tried from a memory stick.  It seems to reach a certain point and just stops opening.  It stops at the colorful splash screen and that's it. No icons, labels, nothing.  I'm assume my problem is an outdated laptop, but any input is appreciated.

CPU: Intel Celeron M 1.4 Ghz
FSB: 400 Mhz
RAM: 256 MB

Comment: I don't quite understand the exact symptoms. You've tagged your question with `freeze`, but you're not describing this. Instead, you seem to mention "stop opening" and "won't run". Please be more specific. *What exactly* do you see at *what point*? Do you see a kernel panic? Do you see a black screen? Or ... And what exact versions of Ubuntu are you trying? Did you select the right architecture? What is the exact hardware? B120 is not specific enough I'm afraid...

Comment: "Celeron M 1.4 Ghz RAM: 256 MB" <-- Well, that explains it.

Comment: Such a cryptic and uninformative answer.  I still have to assume that my laptop is insufficient to run a newer version than 9.04 of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

For that old of a laptop, I really don't think straight up Ubuntu, especially an old version, is the way to go. I would probably go with Lubuntu, or better yet, Debian with LXDE. They are much more lightweight and will still let you run current versions of most software.

Comment: Edited my problem a bit. @gertvdijk I hope it helps